# illegal glutInit() reinitialization attempt: How can I de-initialize glut?

Tags: c++, glut, freeglut

I implemented a class function that call `glutInit()` if the class is activated. Like this:

```
void myViewer::Activate() {
  int argc = 1;
  char* argv[1] = {const_cast<char*>("none")};
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
}
void myViewer::Deactivate() {
  ...
}
```

How can I "de-initialize" the Glut component? Calling the activation function twice throws an error `freeglut (none): illegal glutInit() reinitialization attempt`

Comment: Why are you converting `"none"` a `const char*` to a `char*`?

Comment: I'm new with freeglut, and the initialization code doesn't come from me. It seems to deal with the argument of glutInit `void glutInit(int *argcp, char **argv)`
What is the better implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Initialization](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node9.html) section of the documentation clearly states:

> The primary initialization routine is `glutInit` that should **only be**
> **called exactly once in a GLUT program**.

You are also not using `glutInit` as [specified](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node10.html). Trying to provide fake arguments is asking for trouble. They want the original (`argc`, `argv`) for a reason:

> *glutInit will initialize the GLUT library and **negotiate a session** with the window system.*

Now for a technical reason, closing an OpenGL session on the fly is not a simple task. It requires a careful and thorough shutdown of all OpenGl activities before trying to release the display surface negotiated with the operating system.

Many video games don't even try to do it. They simply grab a window for display and run until the game terminates (one way or another :) ).

And as it happens, glut explicitly forbids you to try.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation kuroi! You meant, I have to pass the `argc` and `argv` from the main function to `glutInit()`? 
The problem is that I try to create a modular and dynmaic class of a GUI application, which can be closed and opened by the user.

Comment: Alas, you can't. glut is not meant for that, it's just a lightweight library that allows to simplify OpenGL access. You can't switch it on and off. You initialize it to grab a render surface from the underlying operating system, do OpenGL stuff, and when you're done, you terminate the program. That's all glut allows to do.